# How to split a pdf page into sections

Tags: linux, pdf

I understand that one can easily split a multi-page pdf into pages. eg using `pdftk`.

But in this case, take for example in a pdf page of newspaper article where a single page may contain several different articles/stories. Wondering if we can split this single pdf page into various sections without resulting to using `GIMP` and treating it as an image (so that the text is still searchable).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There are many tools available to do that. Here's one that has worked for me:

http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php